# Trouble getting the info stored in the structures in the vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am having an issue with my function, it is supposed to print out the list of books stored

```
void PrintBooklist(vector<BookList>&book)
{
    for(int i=0; i<book.size(); i++)
    {   
        if (book[i].memNumBor = -1)
            cout<<book[i].title<<endl;
    }
}
```

but it prints out the word "Title;" a few times but leaves it blank. I check the size at the end to make sure whatever is added is being pushed back and it is, but I cannot read it out. Thanks in advance!

```
int main()
{   
    vector<BookList>book;
    vector<MemInfo>member;
    string memberfile;
    string bookfile;
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;

    cout << "\n\t\t\tWelcome to Library Management Services!"<<endl<<endl;

    Read_Member(member, fin, memberfile);
    Read_Book(book, fin, bookfile);

    SignIn(member, book, fin, fout, memberfile, bookfile); 
    return 0;
}

void Read_Member(vector<MemInfo> &member, ifstream &Fin, string &memberfile) 
{
    MemInfo temp;
    cout<<"Please enter the name of the file that contains the member information: ";
    getline(cin,memberfile);

    Fin.open(memberfile.c_str());

    if(Fin.fail())
    {
        cout<<endl<<"File containing the member information does not exist.\n"<<endl;
        exit (0);
    }

    ReadInfoMem(Fin);
    while (!Fin.eof())
    {   
        member.push_back(temp);
        ReadInfoMem(Fin);
    }
    Fin.close();

    for (int i=0; i<member.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<member[i].lName<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You line **assigns** `memNumBor`

```
if (book[i].memNumBor = -1)
```

What you want is **equality check**

```
if (book[i].memNumBor == -1) // note the double '=='
```

**Update:**

After the edit to add more code, I noticed the following:

```
MemInfo temp;

// ...snip...

ReadInfoMem(Fin);            // presumably this reads the member info from 'Fin'?
while (!Fin.eof())
{   
    member.push_back(temp);  // and you add an *empty* 'temp' object to 'member'
    ReadInfoMem(Fin);
}
```

I expect what is happening is that you're reading from `Fin` in `ReadInfoMem` into a local `MemInfo` variable, but you're not returning the populated `MemInfo` to your enclosing function which adds it to your `member` vector.

I would suggest either a *return-by-value*, or a *pass-by-reference*.

**return-by-value**

```
MemInfo ReadInfoMem(ifstream& fs)
{
    MemInfo temp;
    // populate temp
    return temp;
}

// in your calling code:
temp = ReadInfoMem(Fin);
```

**pass-by-reference**

```
void ReadInfoMem(ifstream& fs, MemInfo& temp)
{
    // populate temp
}

// in your calling code:
ReadInfoMem(Fin, temp);
```

Comment: THank you so much! I did not catch that. Thanks :) 

I think my problem lies in the Read_Member function, The read member function prevents it from working, because there is nothing there. I know for sure its being picked up but its not in the vector after the pushback.  Here is the problematic section. I just added the rest of the code. Thank you again